# Regular expression to match exact substring at the beginning of string

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

I have one substring to be matched exactly at the beginning of source string.

```
source_string = "This is mat. This is cat."

substring1 = "This is"

substring2  = "That is"

source_string.match(/^(#{substring1}|#{substring2})$/)
```

This is what I tried it should work like this, if exact '`This is`' or '`That is`' is there at the beginning of string it should match, doesn't matter what is there after those substrings in `source_string`. My code is giving `nil` even if `'This is'` is present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `$` at the end of the regular expression pattern.

```
source_string.match(/^(#{substring1}|#{substring2})$/)
                                                   ↑
```

By appending `$`, it requires the pattern ends with `This is` or `That is`. You only need `^` at the beginning.

---

```
source_string = "This is mat. This is cat."
substring1 = "This is"
substring2  = "That is"
source_string.match(/^(#{substring1}|#{substring2})/)
# => #<MatchData "This is" 1:"This is">
```

Comment: Oh okay thanks it works I didn't know the use of $ :)

Answer (score 3):

I would not use a regex:

```
[substring1, substring2].any? { |sub| source_string.start_with?(sub) }
  #=> true
```

Comment: Yeah, that. I personally so love regexps, that my code always suffers it :)

Answer (score 1):

While @falsetru is right about the core problem, the regexp is actually still wrong. Whilst the goal is to match a pattern *at a beginning of source string*, not *at the beginning of each line*, the `\A` modifier should be used (see [Regexp::Anchors](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors) for details):

```
source_string = <<-STR
Not to be matched. 
This is cat.
STR
source_string.match(/^This is/) # this should not be matched!
#⇒ #<MatchData "This is">
source_string.match(/\AThis is/)
#⇒ nil
```